# Codeigniter multipage tab form

Tags: codeigniter, plugins

I need to do a very complex form with multiple pages. I would like to be able to use tabs to move between the pages and a single submit button to submit the form. I am using Codeigniter. Is there an add-on or plugin that will handle this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI tabs or something similar for the UI, then CI for handling errors and saving. You can use the form helper as well. There are a million ways to go depending on the need, but hopefully that helps for a starting point.

Comment: I was hoping for a pre-built framework so I didn't have to start from scratch. I am a single programmer on a large project.